# TypeScript: Function parameter types to update an object by key and value

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to write function parameters to update an object's value given the key to update and the new value to update.

```
type SuperMarket = {
    isOpen: boolean;
    offers: string[];
    name: string;
};

const mySuperMarket: SuperMarket = {
    isOpen: true,
    offers: ["banana", "apple", "kiwi"],
    name: "Kwik-E-Mart",
};

// How to make this typesafe?
const updateSupermarket = (key: keyof SuperMarket, value: any) => {
    mySuperMarket[key] = value;
};

// Should work correctly
updateSupermarket("isOpen", true);

// Should throw TypeScript error
updateSupermarket("isOpen", "Aldi");

// Should throw TypeScript error
updateSupermarket("isOpen", ["melon", "milk", "sugar"]);
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is the deal with wrapping it within `updateSupermarket`. Why don't you just say `mySupermarket.isOpen = true`?

Comment: It is just an example. In my real application, the object is a react state and more deeply nested. Also the function is reused in multiple places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a type parameter to capture the key passed in and you can then use an type query to type `value` in relation to the passed in parameter:

```
const updateSupermarket = <K extends keyof SuperMarket>(key: K, value: SuperMarket[K]) => {
    mySuperMarket[key] = value;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrpATgWQIaINYWFAvFAbwCgpSoBLAZwHlIA7ALigCMB7VgGwlToG4SyrAGZCIiSk0rBE5OgHMA2gF1+ZKHVQBbCJOmy5-AL78iAY1Z0pUTSHhI0mbEztiHWHPmJqqtCIyjScBAANAKkwqLiTAoARMw8CTHBUDGoYGBcSSkY5ADu5DFKoWoa2kwxANL5GAC0AKI1DsBJRMZEZhZWCAAmqMAQLoia6O54UAA8FVAQAB79dN2UUFggwrAIriPYAHwAFCtMFckAbqgcQc4bKFvAChVKAJR424Rh1rZXbtgKK0pjp+cIEYTAB6EGwAAWrDgHG6UFyrEwUHMiEQEFMwA4ICIPT6Ayuw0cwF2MR89CygQgD1B4JgUJhcOAEMQrFyUAAKuABqYZGAcGIWYgcWBev1BoT3CSyX4sjEAIKwgrU9pgyHQ2EBZmsjlcmA88h86aoxHC0X4pAS7BSmjk5KxbQcCyyzTkDgYWWUOBydCFalAA)